# List of unchanged SVN files between to svn branches

Tags: svn

How can i find the list of unchanged SVN files between two SVN branches? I tried svn diff --summarize option and it is not giving expected results.

Comment: Are you looking for "unchanged" or "identical" files in your branches?

Answer (score 1):

**Preface**

1. `svn diff --summarize` produced *expected* results, as declared:

> displays the **differences** between two revisions or paths

2. You have to learn Formal Logic course to formulate formal requirements to needed you filelist.

**Face**

According to your description, it seems as "all() - changed()"

- `svn ls -R <ROOT-OF-BRANCH>` *may be* source of full list ("all()")
- Part of `svn diff --summarize` can be, as you have to discover, can be source of changed files list ("changed()")

remove files in second file-list from first - and you'll get "expected" results

**Note:**

from other side, unchanged files have to have in both branches **the same commit-revision** and `svn ls -R -v <ROOT-OF-BRANCH>` for every branch will output tree with all this additional metadata. If you'll normalize filenames (if it's needed - I'm to lazy to test and haven't SVN), you can just diff two lists and find identical lines